# check constraint that references multiple columns in the same table

Tags: sql, db2, constraints, db2-luw

I am attempting to add a constraint to a DB2 database that will check three columns. I am using a table that is an invoice table that includes start date end date quantity item price etc. for each line item on an invoice. I want to prevent allowing start and end date from being null when a column `linestatus = RELELASED`. Here is the alter statement that I have so far. My question is why won't this work?  I have verified that this table does not have any current instances of all three of these checks.

```
alter table pluspgbtrans 
add constraint start_end_notnull 
Check (eip_linestatus = 'RELEASED' AND eip_endate is not null AND eip_startdate is not null)
```

Comment: what error is being returned?  What platform and verison of DB2?

Comment: 10.5 DB2 is the version and the error isDB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-544, SQLSTATE=23512, SQLERRMC=START_END_NOTNULL, DRIVER=4.16.53
[SQL State: 23512]

Comment: That error indicates that an existing row doesn't meet the constraint.

Comment: this query returns null though select * from pluspgbtrans where eip_linestatus = 'RELEASED' and eip_endate is null and eip_startdate is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL statement is valid.

However, your logic has an error: this check does not apply *only* if `eip_linestatus = 'RELEASED'`.

As written, your constraint is asserting that **all rows** must have `eip_linestatus = 'RELEASED' AND eip_endate is not null AND eip_startdate is not null`.

So, if any rows in your table have `eip_linestatus` with a value of anything other than `RELEASED`, you'll get the SQL0544N error when you try to add the constraint.

To create the constraint you're looking for, you need to handle the other state(s) for `eip_linestatus`.  I can't guess what they are, so here's a potential generic option:

```
alter table pluspgbtrans 
    add constraint start_end_notnull check (
        (eip_linestatus <> 'RELEASED') 
        OR
        (
             eip_linestatus = 'RELEASED' 
             AND eip_endate is not null 
             AND eip_startdate is not null
        )
    );
```